# Will dropping the real Amulet of Yendor before spellcasting prevent the extra energy drain?

Tags: nethack

I've got the Amulet, and my character is a proficient spellcaster that does not have any quick ways to regain energy.  The wiki says that "carrying" the amulet incurs a 1 pt - 2n (n=spell energy cost) penalty.  If I'm careful to drop the amulet prior to casting, do I avoid this penaly? Or, is it based on the fact that I have retrieved it?

Answer (score 4):

My apologies, this is something that I should have tried in Wizard Mode. And, in wizmode, the answer is yes.  Dropping the amulet does avoid the penalty.